# Inserir tabulação ao imprimir

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Tenho um código para imprimir cada variável de uma `List`. Estou tentando inserir uma tabulação nessas variáveis. Deem uma olhada no meu código que consta no evento `printPage`:

```
int charactersOnPage = 0;
int linesPerPage = 0;

var Fonte = new Font("Arial", 12);

Cliente cliente = Clientes[listaClientes.SelectedIndex];

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var cli in cliente.Produtos)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("\n\n{0} R${1} Data: {2}", cli.NomeProduto, cli.ValorProduto, cli.DataCompra);
}

e.Graphics.MeasureString(sb.ToString(), Fonte, e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic, out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);

e.Graphics.DrawString(sb.ToString(), Fonte, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

e.HasMorePages = false;
```

Com este código meu *output* é algo como: `Carro R$20000 Data: 08/11/2014`. Eu quero inserir uma tabulação entre esses valores e ter como saída isto:

[image: saída]

Andei tentando com coisas do tipo:

```
RectangleF tabulacao = new RectangleF(30, 10, 100, 122);
e.Graphics.DrawString(System.Convert.ToString(sb), Fonte, Brushes.Blue, tabulacao);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, Rectangle.Round(tabulacao));
```

Não estou sabendo como organizar cada uma dessas variáveis dentro de retângulos para fazer a tabulação. Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda!

Comment: É um relatório, que será impresso?

Comment: Sim, serão impressos todos os produtos comprados pelo cliente que estiver selecionado. O meu código está pronto e a saída como eu quero. A única coisa que necessito é inserir uma tabulação como no exemplo para ficar mais organizado.

Comment: A tabulação usando os RectangleF: você precisa ter pelo menos uma variável para controlar o deslocamento do RectangleF no eixo X

Comment: Você já considerou usar alguma ferramenta de Reporting, ou até mesmo HTML Tables para gerar seu relatório?

Comment: Nunca associei C# com HTML. Me parece ser uma boa ideia.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o mais certo é você usar alguma ferramenta de geração de relatório.

Mas se quiser tentar gerar via HTML, para relatórios simples, de até uma página vai bem:
Coloca um **WebBrowser** na janela, e este código:

```
var HTML = "<html><body><table><tr><td>OK</td></tr></body></html>";
webBrowser.NavigateToString(HTML);
```